# Suggested way to prohibit certain attributes on create in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Spring Data REST has been working exceptionally well for me, but I need to be able to restrict what parameters the user may provide when creating certain resources. For instance, the user should not be able to dictate the ID assigned to the created resource or the activation state of an account, let's say.

My approach to this so far is simply to clear or reset these fields manually in a repository `@HandleBeforeCreate` event handler. Is there another, more clever option for restricting the accepted POST data for a resource?

Additionally, there are cases where a CRUD call needs to specify additional, contextual attributes that are not explicitly part of the target resource but may be used in the process of creating the resource. What is the appropriate way to handle this case?

Comment: If you're using Jackson for serilization, try annotating the attribute and its setter with JsonIgnore, and the getter with JsonGetter. I use this trick to prevent PUTing or PATCHing a new value for the attribute. I haven't tried with POST, though I assume it also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom validator by implementing `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and override `validate(Object object, Errors errors)` and validate the input fields and then populate or make necessary changes to the fields as required to the input request object.

You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring) for more details and also [here](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-validator-initbinder/) for an example.